# How to use the hover affect to make more than one image appear in the same place from more than one mouseover image

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here I have a fairly simple hover affect that once I hover over imageOne, ImageTwo will appear underneath. My aim is to have imageThree next to imageOne and have imageFour appear in the same place as imageTwo. I have used [this](http://jsfiddle.net/daFDn/3261/) to find solutions but my positioning is somewhat different.

Mark up:

```
<ul>
<li>
   <img id="img1" src="imageone.png">
   <img id="img2" src="imagetwo.png">
</li>
<li>
   <img id="img3" src="imagethree.png">
   <img id="img4" src="imagefour.png">
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#img2 {
display: none;
position: absolute;
}
#img1:hover + #img2,
#img2:hover {

display:block;
}
```

Comment: Not sure it's relevant in your case, but it would seem `ul:hover img {display:block;}` covers all the above.

Comment: @Boaz naa your solution positions all the images down the y-axis. I need img3 next to img1

Comment: Positioning is not necessarily related to having the images displayed on hover. You can position the images regardless and then have them all be displayed simultaneously with one selector.